Upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, Is it okay to bypass break-system-packages?
I went through, and still going through links PEP668 and a thread on github forum related to the same
Is it necessary to run these Python related on virtual environment?
What are the risks of bypass break-system-packages?

it is definitely not recommended, but when I did it previously it didn't cause me any issues and I just upgraded all upgradable packages
you can use timeshift to create a complete backup...
update your system and if something goes wrong...
use timeshift to go back...
